# Connect PHP with Paradox .db file on linux server

Tags: php, windows, linux, paradox

I have the following situation:

I have to integrate a website (php on linux server) with an old app (Delphi and Paradox (.db file) on Windows) 
I need get data from paradox database and show them in the website. I can get transfer the .db file by FTP.

I don't think that I can [install external libraries](http://php.net/manual/en/book.paradox.php).

I did not find any command line program on Windows to convert from .db file to mysql or any format that supports PHP.
In addition, Paradox database is updated daily.

Does anyone have any solution or tip or anything?

Comment: Can you just query the Paradox database directly as you need its data?

Comment: I don't know if I understand you. I can't query derectly from Paradox database on the server due to PHP need a library and I haven't remote access from the website server to the PC where paradox database is located but I can send db file by FTP to the website server  (I scheduled a task that sends the file every day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101014/Paradox-database-native-NET-reader) the solution to get data from a paradox .db file without DBE.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Probably best is to write a new stand-alone application for the Windows host that is linked against both the Paradox libraries and the PostgreSQL libraries; make queries against the Paradox database and write the data to the PostgreSQL database.

If you wanted to go half-way and write a tool that dumps the Paradox database into a CSV format for later import on the PostgreSQL end, that could work too, but there is enough hassle in CSV formats that doing the entire transition Paradox -> PostgreSQL in one application seems like the best approach to me.